# sculpting the nose from cube

Tags: sculpting, remesh

As a beginner, I am following this blender tutorial for sculpting the nose but I still cannot not figure out how to smoothen the nose as shown @4.08min at this link https://cloud.blender.org/training/stylized-character-workflow/5d3a1bd54bc3ff1bb9513d3e/

What setting am I missing? I also noticed my nose mesh seems to be of quads instead of trias...

[image]

Comment: in Object mode you can boolean the nose object to the head. Or you can sculpt the nose from the head only, you don't need the nose object. If you want your topology to triangulate, enable Dyntopo.

Comment: @moonboots thanks! looks like sculpting from the head is better! How do I smooth the resulting sculpt... it looks a bit course relative to the head....

Comment: it depends what you call smooth, if you want to flatten, press Shift whatever brush is selected